# How to download attachment from Gmail with specific keyword within subject line and by date

Tags: python, google-api-python-client, gmail-imap

My work requires me to download data (csv file or files) from Gmail every day. I am able to execute the code below for attachment download by email identifier using `fetch()`, but I want to download attachment by specific keywords in the subject line and option of selecting specific date such as today or another date.

I am not sure where to add the keyword and date function in the code below and how to add it.

I have attached my current code below:

```
import imaplib
import email
import os

attachment_dir = 'file/directory'

# account credentials
user = 'email_adress@gmail.com'
password = 'password'
imap_url = 'imap.gmail.com'

def get_body(msg):
    if msg.is_multipart():
        return get_body(msg.get_payload(0))
    else:
        return msg.get_payload(None, True)  # decode

def search(key, value, connection):
    result, data = connection.search(None, key, '"{}"'.format(value))
    return data

def get_emails(result_bytes):
    msgs = []  # all the email data are pushed inside an array
    for num in result_bytes[0].split():
        typ, data = connection.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        msgs.append(data)

    return msgs # it will return an array of bytes separating each email

def get_attachment(msg):
    for part in msg.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
            continue
        if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
            continue
        fileName = part.get_filename()

        if bool(fileName):
            filePath = os.path.join(attachment_dir, fileName)
            if not os.path.isfile(filePath) :
                fp = open(filePath, 'wb')
                fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
                fp.close()

connection = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_url)
connection.login(user, password)
connection.select('INBOX')

result, data = connection.fetch(b'91', '(RFC822)') # fetch the email body (RFC822) for the given ID, b'91' is the id of the email, you can get it from the search function
raw = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
print(get_body(raw)) # prints the raw text of the whole email

print(search('FROM', 'email.source@gmail.com',connection)) # search and return uids instead

print(get_attachment(raw)) # pass the email to the function
```

Thank you very much for your help, really appreciate it.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Apologies in advance that I am afraid I can't really help clarify the code I wrote because I don't have much experience in this field, and most codes are referenced from other sources.

Comment: You need to refine your question. It is too broad.

Comment: Hi @CaptainCaveman, thanks for the comment. Could you advise how to refine it?

Comment: Which part of the code doesn't do what you want? Which are the conditions it should implement?

Comment: Hi @tripleee. I want the code to download the attachment or attachments if the subject line contains the keyword I want, such as "daily report". Also, the code can help filter the date I want, such as the latest date or another date I want.  I am not sure how to add these conditions to my current code. I hope I have clarified the question. Let me know if you have other questions. Thanks.